# drawable/abc_vector_test not found after updating Android Studio and the Support Library

Tags: android

I recently update to Android Studio 3 and support libraries 27. I don't know which one caused this issue. I can't even reproduce it, I only get reports on Crashlytics. It can't find some drawable that it's not even mine. This is happening on my splash screen which doesn't even load a layout, just launches other activities.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/mypackage.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable mypackage:drawable/abc_vector_test with resource ID #0x7f080058
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable mypackage:drawable/abc_vector_test with resource ID #0x7f080058

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080058
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:775)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1640)
       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java)
       at mypackage.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from xml type drawable resource ID #0x7f080058
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:1048)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:763)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1640)
       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java)
       at mypackage.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml
       at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(AssetManager.java)
       at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:593)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:1029)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:763)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1640)
       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java)
       at mypackage.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I have this `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` on my default config on gradle. I use vectors on my code and they work just fine. I use them on the main module and other modules.

Comment: I get this rare but random on 4.x

Answer (score 0):

on whixh device it crashes android api kess then 5(lolipop)?

Comment: 5 and 7 so far. Huawei and Samsung. I only have a few crashes, 11 users total but I only have this version in beta.

Comment: @casolorz try this one 

    public void onCreate() { 
        super.onCreate();
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true); 
    }

Comment: I thought that wasn't necessary anymore? Also didn't that have some memory leak issues? And why do all my vectors work fine?

Comment: need to investigate if this fix will help. which gradle and buildtools are u using?

Comment: I'm on build tools 26.0.2, maybe that's the issue, I should be on 27 I think. I'm also on 4.1

Comment: i saw somewhere that it was same issue with build tools 24+. try to set buildtools 24 or lower. But generally support libraries recommended to be same version as buildtools version.

Comment: I'm not sure I can go down to 24 with my current config but I'll try 27.0.1

Comment: @casolorz did you find the fix for this?